# Trigonometric polynomials are dense in continuous $1$ periodic functions - proof

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

In the accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4159649/155881), the claim is made that trigonometric polynomials are dense in $1$ periodic continuous functions.

I take this to mean for example, that if we consider

$$f(x) = x-\lfloor x \rfloor$$

we can approximate it to an arbitrary degree with an expression of the form:

$$f(x) =  \operatorname{Re}\left( \sum_m c_m e^{2\pi i m} \right)$$

Is my understanding of the statement correct? And how would I go about proving it?

---

EDIT: It was pointed out that the fractional part function isn't continuous. However, I've seen others recommending approximating it with trigonometric polynomials as well. See [here](https://mathhelpforum.com/threads/fractional-part-and-integration.122635/) for example. The question then becomes, can we prove that the fractional part function can be approximated with trigonometric polynomials?

Comment: I don't think your function is continuous...

Comment: You're right. In that case, I guess the proof at the link provided doesn't hold?

Comment: Since Fourier series can be generated, the partial sums will be a good approximation, except at the jump.  (Gibbs's phenomenon).

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to approximate the fractional part function. It seems to me that the periodicity of the $g$ in the answer you cite is taking care of this $\text{mod}\, 1$ operation, while the fact that convergence takes place for every continuous $g$ is equivalent to the convergence in distribution that they claim. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: @Jose27 - the claim in the proof was made of trigonometric polynomials. But it was used for the mod 1 function. Doesn't this mean we should be able to approximate the mod 1 function arbitrarily with trigonometric polynomials for it to work?

Comment: @herbsteinberg - does this jump pose a problem in the linked proof?

Comment: If they were using it for what you say, the only thing they'd be able to conclude is that $\mathbb{E}(S_n-\floor{S_n})$ converges to the right thing, which is not enough to prove convergence in distribution. I'd suggest going over the Portmanteau lemma.

Comment: @RohitPandey  Sorry - I haven't tried to examine the linked proof (and I wont - too long).  Fourier series converges to midpoint at jump.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment or observation for the OP, but it fits better in this section.

The answer in the link you are referring to shows that, under a non degeneracy condition $|\gamma_m|<1$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$,  (which fails for instance when $X_1$ is supported in $\mathbb{Z}$), for any continuous function $f$ on the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$
$$E[f(e^{2\pi iS_n})]\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^1_0f(e^{2\pi ix})\,dx$$
This is equivalent to saying that the distribution of $e^{2\pi iS_n}$ (which is a random variable in $\mathbb{S}^1$) converges weakly to the uniform distribution on $\mathbb{S}^1$, that is, the ***normalized arc-length measure*** on the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$.

---

The identification of $\mathbb{S}^1$ with $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ allows us to be a little loose and consider functions on $\mathbb{S}^1$ as $1$ periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}$, or as functions on $\mathbb{R}\operatorname{mod}1$. The geometric picture is the of wrapping the real line around the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$, but of course this can be done rigorously with simple topological arguments.

---

To conclude *rigorously* that the law of $S_n-\lfloor S_n\rfloor$ converges weakly to the uniform distribution $U(0,1)$, one may use the following observations:

1. $e^{2\pi ix}=e^{2\pi i\{x\}}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where $\{x\}:=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.
2. The function $\phi:[0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ given by $x\mapsto e^{2\pi ix}$ is continuous and bijective; the inverse $\phi^{-1}:\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow[0,1)$ which maps $z=e^{2\pi i\theta}\mapsto\{\theta\}$ is measurable and continuous in $\mathbb{S}^1\setminus\{1\}$. The point of discontinuity has arc-length measure $0$.

Recall the following result from Probability (Billingsley, P., ***Convergence of Probability measures***, Wiley 1968)

> Theorem: Suppose $(S,d)$, $(S',d')$ are metric spaces, and that $\{\mu_n,\mu:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are Borel measures on $(S,d)$ such that $\mu_n\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\Longrightarrow}\mu$. If $f:S\rightarrow S'$ is a measurable function that is continuous $\mu$-almost surely (i.e. the set of discontinuities $D_f$ of $f$ has measure $\mu(D_f)=0$), then $\mu_n\circ f^{-1}\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\Longrightarrow}\mu\circ f^{-1}$, that is, for any $g\in\mathcal{C}_b(S')$,
> $$\lim_n\int_Sg(f(x))\,\mu_n(dx)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_S g(f(x))\,\mu(dx)$$

In terms of random variables, the result says that of $X_n$, $X$ are random variables with values in $S$ and $X_n\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\Longrightarrow} X$, then $f(X_n)\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\Longrightarrow}f(X)$

An application of the theorem above implies that $\phi^{-1}(e^{2\pi iS_n})=S_n-\lfloor S_n\rfloor \stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\Longrightarrow} U(0,1)$, where $U(0,1)$ is the uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1)$.

Comment: What is the set $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: It is the circle $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}$